# Pluralsight react course using jscomplete TypeError

Tags: reactjs, typeerror

I am following a Pluralsight course and got stuck on some React instructions.  The course is using a site called jscomplete.  The exact URL for this particular course is as follows:

https://jscomplete.com/playground/rgs2.1

Literally following this course line for line, here is the exact code from the course:

```
class App extends React.Components {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="header">{this.props.title}</div>
        <Card />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App title="The GitHub Cards App" />,
  mountNode,
);
```

After running the code, I get the following on screen error:

```
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
```

The jscomplete site is supposed to already have the necessary dependencies, so I'm not sure why I am getting the error.

Comment: If you use an appropriate IDE, this will highlight the problem for you. I use PhpStorm, and I expect WebStorm and VS Code would also catch it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo, it should be 
`class App extends React.Component`

and not 
`React.Components`

Comment: You gotta be kidding me... How the heck did you see that, and I've been staring at this for 20 minutes?  Thank you, kind sir.  This worked.